# How to "fix" this installer does not support Admin or Advertised installations

Tags: windows-installer

I have an msi that I need to extract.  When I run msiexec /a on it, I get "this installer does not support Admin or Advertised installations".  I've read other posts on Stack Overflow stating that it's possible to tweak an .msi to allow Admin installs.  I have Super Orca, does anyone know what changes I need to make to an .msi to allow Admin installs?

Comment: It might be simpler to launch the installer in normal mode, leave it sitting at the first dialog, and search for the extracted files, which IIRC are usually in the user's TEMP directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how this logic check is implemented and then void it out either by editing the MSI or creating a transform and applying the transform during the administrative installation.

Typically this type of check would have been implemented in the LaunchConditions table or as a Type 19 error custom action scheduled in the AdminInstallUI and AdminInstallExecute sequences.  It's hard to say how exactly without having a copy of the MSI and/or log file generated when attempting to do an admin installation.